# Android SQLite getColumnIndex

Tags: android, sqlite

This is the code from the contract class setting up the table columns

```
  public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tools";
    public static final String COLUMN_TOOL_TYPE = "type";
    public static final String COLUMN_COST = "cost";
    public static final String COLUMN_IN_STOCK = "in_stock";
    public static final String COLUMN_STOCK_LEVEL = "stock_quantity";
    public static final String COLUMN_PICTURE = "picture";
```

The database is being created fine and I can add dummy data and I have added a sample drawable to the COLUMN_PICTURE column. But when I use

```
 int imgColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToolEntry.COLUMN_PICTURE);
```

To clarify this line comes from the bindView method

```
int typeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToolEntry.COLUMN_TOOL_TYPE);
int costColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToolEntry.COLUMN_COST);
int stockLevelColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToolEntry.COLUMN_STOCK_LEVEL);
int indicatorStock = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToolEntry.COLUMN_IN_STOCK);
int imgColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToolEntry.COLUMN_PICTURE);
```

All the other columnindex gets work. I did add the picture column in after the others. But i have cleared the cache/stored data in the app and uninstalled it.

it always returns -1. The cursor is working as it returns the correct values for other columns. Shown below is a dump of the SQLite database with dummy data. I then over wrote the BLOB entry for the second row with a zero. So I can using content values 
    values.put(ToolEntry.COLUMN_PICTURE, 0);

[image: Image of Database]

But when I try to use
    toolImg = cursor.getBlob(imgColumnIndex);

It crashes as the index is at -1

Comment: This is the link to the image on Dropbox  [link](https://photos-6.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAdKzP9kbF_QLjsQJh2SbHgDbK375I3MLc5_jzVNfZVeg/12/1129520/png/32x32/3/1496955600/0/2/tools.png/EM7Tfhi6ycLHASAHKAc/gLQcLzeqzPrRgeTrF31kMXVIxfQUxi8DwgwHxMHyqNo?dl=0&size=2048x1536&size_mode=3)

Comment: Where do you get the cursor from?

Comment: This is taken from the bindView method int typeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToolEntry.COLUMN_TOOL_TYPE); int costColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToolEntry.COLUMN_COST); int stockLevelColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToolEntry.COLUMN_STOCK_LEVEL); int indicatorStock = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToolEntry.COLUMN_IN_STOCK); int imgColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ToolEntry.COLUMN_PICTURE); All of the other lines getting ColumnIndex work fine. – David Crowley 1 min ago    edit

Comment: Show the code that creates the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a silly mistake on my part. I had defined my projection correctly in one place but had left out the new column in another projection definition.